# How to get variables value using java reflection

Tags: java

I have class as -

```
public class demo {
public String screenshotpath="No ScreenShot";
public void methodfail(){
    //setting variable value depending on execution status
    screenshotpath="c://screenshot.jpg";
}
```

I want to access variable screenshotpath -

```
    Field[] fields = demo.getDeclaredFields();
    for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].setAccessible(true);
System.out.println(fields[i].get(object of demo).toString());}
```

Above line prints default value always i.e. "No ScreenShot". But i want to access value i set in methodmail method i.e. c://screenshotpath.jpg

Comment: Have you called `methodfail` on the `object of demo` instance? Are you sure? Have you checked with your debugger? Also, `object of demo` isn't a valid varaible name. Please post **real** code.

Comment: In this example you are not calling methodfail, ensure your calling it before executing get on the field object

Comment: You should also consider using some best practices, because example code should be exemplary (according to Joshua Bloch)!